# Oozie job scheduling is causing timeout error

Tags: apache-spark, ssh, oozie

I have encountered an issue while running the Spark job through Oozie, as there is dependent jobs like first job will trigger second job, second job will trigger third job in some cases i am getting timeout error as SparkContext is not created and  the final data failed  to get loaded to Hive,

I have 5 interdependent jobs scheduled in Oozie through oozie-Ssh Action.

let me know i will paste the error if my description doesn't makes sense

Comment: Any particular reason to use an ssh action instead of Spark actions?

Comment: @LiMuBei  yes we are using the output file to load into Hive Table,

Answer (score 0):

This is very common when there is a memory problem, you need to specify memory per executor and how many executors. Calculate your limitations on cluster and set that variables.

```
spark-submit --master yarn-cluster --executor-memory 1g --num-executors 3
```